# Django Add Scond Static Files URL

Tags: django, url, django-templates, django-urls, filepath

I am using Django with a Bootstrap template, that requires Jquery. But I am having trouble with a js file.

I created **static** directory, and **static_cdn** directory.

I am using a Bootstrap 4 template.

My project template requires a js file *(template doesn't working correctly without this js file)* but this js file is not using a valid url; It is calling all my svg files, **but with a nonvalid URL**.

---

This is my project static files folder :

[image: Project Static files]

---

This is my urls.py urls :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^panel/$', panelView, name='panel'),
    url(r'^pageOne/$', pageOne, name='pageOne'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is my settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static"),
    # '/var/www/static/',
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
MEDIA_URL = '/evrak/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "evrak")
```

This is my html page :

```
    <!-- BEGIN: Vendor JS-->
    <script src="{% static 'app-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'app-assets/fonts/LivIconsEvo/js/LivIconsEvo.tools.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'app-assets/fonts/LivIconsEvo/js/LivIconsEvo.defaults.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'app-assets/fonts/LivIconsEvo/js/LivIconsEvo.min.js' %}"></script>
    {% block vendorJS %}
    {% endblock vendorJS %}
    <!-- END Vendor JS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Page Vendor JS-->
    {% block pageVendorJS %}
    {% endblock pageVendorJS %}
    <!-- END: Page Vendor JS-->
```

---

Now,
Django is able to load everything in **static** directory. And also everything is working correctly.

**But,** a js file is calling my all svg files , *and it is using a nonvalid url.*

This is my problematic js file :

> > "{% static 'app-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js' %}"

This is my errors :

[image: Error with vendors.min.js]

You can see '**initiator**' field that shows who is calling files. 
So, all '*red*' files' initiator is '**vendor.min.js**'.

If you look, problem is all about this 'vendors.min.js' file. Django is loading everything correctly first, but after loading this js file, it is calling all svg files with a nonvalid url; so browser throws 404 not found error.

---

Normally everything is correct like that :

[image: True Address]

Django is loading everything correctly , but this *vendors.min.js* thing is calling all files in a wrong way, so Django can not find them.

I couldnt find how to change this js file to call a valid address, or add 'app-assets' url directory to Django.

How can I fix this problem ?

I think , if I can add a static url path starts with '/app-assets/' directly , all will work . But for now couldn't find, how to add a second static url path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Added a new path that uses directory, and solved.

This is new settings :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_URL2 = '/app-assets/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static"),
    # '/var/www/static/',
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
STATIC_ROOT2 = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn/app-assets")

MEDIA_URL = '/evrak/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "evrak")
```

This is new urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^panel/$', panelView, name='panel'),
    url(r'^pageOne/$', pageOne, name='pageOne'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL2, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT2)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Now, everything is working.
both 
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/app-assets/fonts/LivIconsEvo/svg/share.svg' 
and
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/app-assets/fonts/LivIconsEvo/svg/share.svg'
links are valid now.